# Function of this graph pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, graph, pseudocode, depth-first-search

```
procedure explore(G; v)
Input: G = (V;E) is a graph; v 2 V
Output: visited(u) is set to true for all nodes u reachable from v


visited(v) = true
previsit(v)
for each edge (v; u) 2 E:
if not visited(u): explore(u)
postvisit(v)
```

All this pseudocode does is find one path right? It does nothing while backtracking if I'm not wrong?

Comment: looks like flood fill, but what is the problem/question?

Comment: @Absurd-Mind What I don't understand is that will it find just one path right from a given node v? Unlike DFS?

Comment: this algorithm does not care about paths. It marks (or colors them) all nodes which are reachable from `v`. The path to reach each node may or may not be the shortest. And it is DFS.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind Could you show this algo running on a sample graph?

Comment: Assume G=[this graph](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~pribeiro/estagio2008/usaco/2_1_Flood_Fill_arquivos/flood1.gif) and v=6. Then just follow your algorithm. If you see the line `visited(v) = true`, strike this node.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind thanks! Btw one more thing. The visited array: is it a global array or a local one whose value depends on the activation record we are in while recursing?

Comment: The normal approach would be to store the visited information inside each node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just explores the graph (it doesn't return a path) - everything that's reachable from the starting vertex will be explored and have the corresponding value in `visited` set (not just the vertices corresponding to one of the paths).

It moves on to the next edge while backtracking ... and it does `postvisit`.

So if we're at `a`, which has edges to `b`, `c` and `d`, we'll start by going to `b`, then, when we eventually return to `a`, we'll then go to `c` (if it hasn't been visited already), and then we will similarly go to `d` after return to `a` for the 2nd time.

It's called [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), in case you were wondering. Wikipedia also gives an example of the order in which vertices will get explored in a tree: (the numbers correspond to the visit order, we start at `1`)

[image]

In the above, you're not just exploring the vertices going down the left (`1`-`4`), but after `4` you go back to `3` to visit `5`, then back to `2` to visit `6`, and so on, until all 12 are visited.

With regard to `previsit` and `postvisit` - `previsit` will happen when we first get to a vertex, `postvisit` will happen after we've explored all of it's children (and their descendants in the corresponding DFS tree). So, in the above example, for `1`, `previsit` will happen right at the start, but post-visit will happen only at the very end, because all the vertices are children of `1` or descendants of those children. The order will go something like:

> pre 1, pre 2, pre 3, pre 4, post 4, pre 5, post 5, post 3, pre 6, post 6, post 2, ...

Comment: "comes back to a" may be misleading. There is also previsit, so the order would be: `preA, preB, postB, preC, postC, preD, postD, postA`

Comment: @Absurd-Mind True. Edited to include that information.